# Doing a lot of heavy lifting in the marionette router with lots of dependencies. Need a better set-up

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-routing

Still a noob a mariontette.js

I'm using Require.js and Marionette.js together.

I have one router and this is the basic view of it.

```
define([many, many dependencies],function(many,many names of the dependecies)

{
  return marionette.AppRouter.extend
  routes :{
     bunch of routes : function names
  } 

  function1 : function()
  {
    make a collection/fill collection (collection may be already initialized at top)
    make the views
    show/render the regions with the layouts and views and collections
  }

  .
  .
  .  
}
```

So currently, all my views and collections are dependencies in my router. I then initialize the proper views and collections and show them when necessary within the router when the route is called. I hope you can get the picture. This worked well for me at first. But now my dependency list for this one router is getting huge. Everytime the router loads, it has to retrieve all the templates of each dependency which is unecessary. I want to fix this but I'm not sure how to approach it.

A list of things I probably should do and some questions I have:

-Put all those methods in separate controllers(hah I do not use one currently)

-Split it up into multiple routers <-- How do I use the proper router when a specific route is called. Would this help with my dependency issue so that not all templates are retrieved at the same time?

-Do I need initializers in my views? I'm not using the marionette module system since I'm using require.js so I'm not sure if an initializer can be used for my separate modules(views,collections,etc). The reason I make my collections within the router functions is because composite views take in the collection as an option so the collection needs to be there when the view is made and shown.

**If anyone has suggestions on how I should make my giant router better I would be very grateful.**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So I researched some more and found some stackoverflow questions and answers that will be the solution I will follow for now.

[Backbone.js "fat router" design conundrum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14185909/backbone-js-fat-router-design-conundrum)

This question right here is basically the same thing I am facing. I have a fat router. The answer fencliff provided looks good because it's what I wanted to do. He's splitting the routers and **lazy loading** the dependencies for each route. This is exactly something I wanted to do because my router was loading every dependency from the start.

For marionette.js the multiple router set-up can look like this

[Multiple Routers and Controllers with require.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13806693/multiple-routers-and-controllers-with-require-js)

The controllers of each router would hold the functions with lazy loading require.js dependencies.

I'm not saying this is a good solution. I'm still open to answers if anyone will provide. But for now I'll be doing this.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience so far, the Router should be just about forward/backward navigation of pages. There is a great tutorial on getting started with MarionetteJS here: http://www.backbonerails.com/ - You'll see that to switch from one 'component' to another, can be very cleanly done with Application events, such as described here: https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.application.md#appvent-event-aggregator

Comment: I do not have an issue with switching and loading components. I was doing it fine in the router I had. The issue is that I want to load the dependencies when they are need instead of my router loading all dependencies at once.

Comment: then you might be looking for the module pattern? AMD can help to control when dependencies are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

The way I'm doing this with my router is to not load the class as a dependency in the module's define call but rather when the event is fired that requires that I load the module.

My marionette's router routes with

define(['marionette',
        'appDispatcher',
        'router/routeController'],

```
function(Marionette,
         dispatcher,
         controller){

    var router, routerDefinition;

    routerDefinition = Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
        controller: controller,
        appRoutes: {
            'login': 'showLogin',
            'menu': 'showMenu',
            'inventory': 'showInventory',
            ...
            '*path': 'defaultPathAction'
        }
    });
```

...

Then my controller loads those modules like this:

```
define([], function(){
    controller = {
      showInventory: function(){
        require(['module/path/name'], function(Module){
          currentView = new Module();
          mainView.mainContent.show(currentView);
        });
      },
    ...
    }
```

This way your assets aren't loaded up front; only when that particular module is needed.  And that module will load all the way down the dependancy chain before executing.  Very handy I think.  The same thing could really be done without Marionette and the router controller; just with a plain 'ol Backbone Router.