# How to properly resolve circular dependency in require.js

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

I have following module configuration:
`Global -> Collections -> Favorites` (global requires collections, collections require favorites).

At the same time `Favorites` also need `Global` module (for its' other properties).

Sample code:

```
define("global", ["collections"], function(Collections) {
    console.log("Defining global");

    var Global = {
        env: "home",
        collections: Collections
    };

    return Global;
});
define("collections", ["favorites"], function(Favorites) {
    console.log("Defining collections");

    var collections = {
        likes: function() {},
        favorites: Favorites
    };

    return collections;
});
define("favorites", ["global"], function(Global) {
    console.log("Defining favorites");

    var Favorites = function(name) {
        console.log(Global.env)
        this.name = name;
    };
    return Favorites;
});

require(["global"], function(Global) {
    console.log("global", Global);
    console.log("collections", Global.collections);
    console.log("favorites", Global.collections.favorites);

    var Favorites = Global.collections.favorites;
    Favorites();
});
```

I've also created jsfiddle for this case: http://jsfiddle.net/NBSzC/

As you can see this codes produces error as we are trying to read value (`env`) from `undefined`.

Here on StackOverflow there is other helpful ticket on the same case: [How to handle circular dependencies with RequireJS/AMD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881059/how-to-handle-circular-dependencies-with-requirejs-amd)

Using it I was able to make it "work", please check following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NBSzC/1/

And the issue here is in the fact that I had to use

```
console.log(Global.Global.env)
```

as original Global now points to exports object and there we've set up link to Global as Global.

We could also do following in the Global module but I believe this is another hack:

```
_.extend( exports, Global );
```

In the corresponding link there was no such problem at all, not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I have the feeling that circular dependencies are a "smell" that the code organization suffers.

In your case I would argue that you do *not* need the `collections` field in globals. If something depends on collections, why not ask for the collections module directly?

In this case the dependencies will be: Collections → Favorites → Globals (but Globals does not point back to Favorites, thus the circle is broken).

Then, if you really need to load everything from the beginning, you could modify the `require()` call:

```
require(["global","collections"], function(Global,Collections) { ...
```

Or define a bootstrap module that requires everything and require that:

```
define("bootstrap",["global","collections","favorites"], function(...) { ...
require("bootstrap", ...)
```

Of course I do not have all the details of your project, so the solution may be different. But still the main point is that circular dependencies are a smell.