# How to handle circular dependencies?

Tags: requirejs, circular-dependency

Given:

- `StringPreconditions` extends `ObjectPreconditions`
- `ObjectPreconditions` depends on `StringPreconditions` (one of its methods returns the subclass)
- `Preconditions` is a gatekeeper to `ObjectPreconditions` and `StringPreconditions` (making sure they both load before returning an instance)
- `User` depends on `Preconditions`

I have this code:

```
define(["ObjectPreconditions"], function(ObjectPreconditions)
{
  console.log("Inside StringPreconditions");

  function StringPreconditions() {}
  StringPreconditions.prototype = Object.create(ObjectPreconditions.prototype);
  StringPreconditions.prototype.constructor = ObjectPreconditions;
  return StringPreconditions;
});

define(["require"], function(require)
{
  console.log("Inside ObjectPreconditions");

  // Resolve circular dependencies
  var StringPreconditions;
  require(["StringPreconditions"], function(theStringPreconditions)
  {
    StringPreconditions = theStringPreconditions;
    console.log("ObjectPreconditions finished loading StringPreconditions");
  });

  function ObjectPreconditions() {}
  ObjectPreconditions.prototype.isInstanceOf(type)
  {
    console.log("ObjectPreconditions.isInstanceOf() invoked");
    if (type === String)
      return new StringPreconditions();
  }
});

define(["ObjectPreconditions", "StringPreconditions"], function(ObjectPreconditions, StringPreconditions)
{
  console.log("Inside Preconditions");
  var Preconditions = {};

  Preconditions.requireThat(parameter) = function()
  {
    return new ObjectPreconditions(parameter);
  };
  return Preconditions;
});

define(["Preconditions"], function(Preconditions)
{
  console.log("Inside User");
  function User() {}
  User.prototype.doSomething = function()
  {
    var StringPrecondition = Preconditions.requireThat("test").isInstanceOf(String);
  }
});
```

The problem is that 10% of the time I get this load order:

- Inside User
- Inside Preconditions
- Inside ObjectPreconditions
- Inside StringPreconditions
- ObjectPreconditions.isInstanceOf() (**CRASH** because StringPreconditions is undefined)
- ObjectPreconditions finished loading StringPreconditions

I've already read http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#circular but I believe they are doing the same thing I am.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42264822/14731 contains an updated answer for ES6 modules.

---

I figured it out: We need to create a "gatekeeper" file that will define functions that depend on the circular dependencies.

1. Rename `ObjectPreconditions.js` to `AbstractObjectPreconditions.js`.
2. Create a new `ObjectPreconditions.js` file (our new gatekeeper).
3. Move any circular dependencies out of `AbstractObjectPreconditions.js` into `ObjectPreconditions.js`
4. User code should `require(ObjectPreconditions)`. Code involved in the circular dependency (e.g. subclasses) should `require(AbstractObjectPreconditions)`.

Here is what the resulting code looks like:

```
define(["AbstractObjectPreconditions"], function(ObjectPreconditions)
{
  console.log("Inside StringPreconditions");

  function StringPreconditions() {}
  StringPreconditions.prototype = Object.create(ObjectPreconditions.prototype);
  StringPreconditions.prototype.constructor = ObjectPreconditions;
  return StringPreconditions;
});

define(["require"], function(require)
{
  console.log("Inside AbstractObjectPreconditions");

  function ObjectPreconditions() {}
  return ObjectPreconditions;
});

define(["AbstractObjectPreconditions"], function(ObjectPreconditions)
{
  // Gatekeeper for circular dependencies
  ObjectPreconditions.prototype.isInstanceOf(type)
  {
    console.log("ObjectPreconditions.isInstanceOf() invoked");
    if (type === String)
      return new StringPreconditions();
  }

  return ObjectPreconditions;
});


define(["ObjectPreconditions", "StringPreconditions"], function(ObjectPreconditions, StringPreconditions)
{
  console.log("Inside Preconditions");
  var Preconditions = {};

  Preconditions.requireThat(parameter) = function()
  {
    return new ObjectPreconditions(parameter);
  };
  return Preconditions;
});

define(["Preconditions"], function(Preconditions)
{
  console.log("Inside User code");
  function User() {}
  User.prototype.doSomething = function()
  {
    var StringPrecondition = Preconditions.requireThat("test").isInstanceOf(String);
  }
});
```

Comment: this may be correct, but I find very difficult to follow, can you simplify variable names etc?