# ES6 Modules and Circular Dependency

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-6, circular-dependency, es6-modules

I'm having this problem in ES6 in a Babel Environment:

```
// A.js
class A {
}
export default new A();

// B.js
import C from './C';
class B {
}
export default new B();

// C.js
import A from './A';
import B from './B';
class C {
    constructor(A, B){
        this.A = A;
        this.B = B; // undefined
    }
}
export default new C(A, B)
```

I import them like this:

```
// stores/index.js
import A from './A';
import B from './B';
import C from './C';

export {
    A,
    B,
    C
}
```

And from my app entry point I do:

```
import * as stores from './stores';
```

I would (hoped) expected the order of execution to be A -> B ->C but in reality it is A-> C-> B.
This is due to module B importing C, so that the C module is evaluated before the B module. This creates a problem in the setup of C because in that case **B** would be **undefined**.

I've seen a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38841469/how-to-fix-this-es6-module-circular-dependency) but I'm not sure the init function is the best solution here, it seems a bit hacky.

**Q**: What's the best practise about solving this kind of circular dependencies in ES6 that would possibly work in different environments (Babel, Rollup)?

Comment: *expected the order of execution to be A -> B ->C* - for which entry point? Why is C imported in B if it's not even used?

Comment: It is used, that is an example missing implementation details. I've update the question adding the entry point

Comment: Omitted details change everything here. There won't be circular dependency because unused import is skipped. Consider providing http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Also using classes solely for singletons is antipattern.

Comment: `A` and `B` in `new C()` are undefined because you passed no arguments to your constructor, not because the imports didn't work.

Comment: @Bergi thanks, it was a simplification mistake, I do pass the imported modules as arguments to my C constructor, I've edited the question. What would you suggest to crete singletons instead and why class instances are mistakes? I've seen it everywhere as a common pattern

Comment: @Leonardo If you want real singletons, just use object literals - no need for `class`, `new` and prototype inheritance. Or even better use multiple named exports. Those `class` instances aren't even [actually singletons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38741262/1048572), they can be re-instantiated. If you want that, better be explicit about it and export the class itself - and instantiate it in your tests, your main application script etc.

Comment: CommonJS made this so much easier. ES6 is a step backwards.

Answer (score 17):

> What's the best practice about circular dependencies in ES6?

Avoid them altogether. If you cannot (or don't want to) completely avoid them, restrict the involved modules to *only* use function declarations with circular dependencies, never initialise top-level values (constants, variables, classes) by using imported values (that includes `extends` references).

> What would possibly work in different environments (Babel, Rollup)?

The order of module resolution and initialisation is defined in the ES6 specification, so this should be the same in all ES6 environments - regardless how the modules are loaded and how their identifiers are resolved.

> How to solve this kind of circular dependencies setup?

If you do have a circular dependency `X -> Y -> Z -> … -> X -> …`, you need to establish a start point. Say you want `X` to be loaded first, although it depends on `Y`, so you need to make sure that `X` never uses any of the imported values until all modules in the circle are completely initialised. So you break the circle between `X` and `Y`, and you will need to start the import chain at `Y` - it will recursively traverse the dependencies until it stops at `X`, which has no further dependencies that are not already getting initialised, so it will be the first module to be evaluated.

The rule you have to follow then is to *always* import `Y` before importing *any* of the other modules in the circle. If you even once do not use this common single entry point to the circle, your house of cards will collapse.

In your particular example, this means that `index.js` will need to use

```
import A from './A';
import C from './C'; // entry point to circular dependencies
import B from './B';
…
```

Comment: If we are compiling to ESM - is this as important?

Comment: @httpete It's important when you're *writing* ESM. What else would you be compiling from?

Comment: This seems like a big oversight, especially with many extensions automatically rearranging imports. Circular dependencies have always been perfectly normal, they're the whole reason forward declarations exist, and dependencies in implementation were not an issue since it would be in a different file. Not having proper support for them in a modern language seems wild.

Comment: @riv There *is* proper support for forward declarations, i.e. declaring imports that will be called from functions that are defined before the imports are instantiated. If you only do that, and don't actually already call the function during the circular module instantiation, you're good - and the evaluation order does not matter. It's depending on the order of imports declarations that should be avoided. (If you can't avoid it, extensions that rearrange imports can usually be disabled on a per-line or per-file basis).