# Access imported module in top level scope of file with 'circular' dependency?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, es6-modules

I have the following modules structure:

```
/components
├── Button.js
├── Checkbox.js
├── index.js
├── DateSelect
    ├── DateSelect.js
    └── index.js
```

With `/components/DateSelect/index.js`:

```
import DateSelect from './DateSelect';

export default DateSelect;
```

`/components/index.js`:

```
import DateSelect from './DateSelect';
import Button from './Button';
import Checkbox from './Checkbox';

export {
  DateSelect,
  Button,
  Checkbox,
};
```

And `/components/DateSelect/DateSelect.js`:

```
import { Checkbox } from '../';
// ...code

// I want to do this!
const MyCustomCheckbox = props => <Checkbox style={someStyle} />;

// ...code
class DateSelect extends React.Component {
  // code
}
export default DateSelect;
```

Now, I want to access `Checkbox` as in the code above, in the top level scope of the file, but I get `undefined`. If I access this variable, however, in the `render` method of `DateSelect`, it works as expected.

I'm not completely sure on why this is the case, or how I can fix this (I can do `import Checkbox from '../Checkbox'`, but I don't want to change the pattern of using the `index.js` file of the directory), and I also want to understand exactly what's going on. Any ideas?

Comment: Why does `Checkbox.js` depend on `Dateselect.js`? Can you post its code please?

Comment: @Bergi sure, give me a few minutes to get to my computer, but checkbox doesn’t depend on DateSelect, the circular dependency I talked about was between DateSelect.js and components/index.js, importing modules from each other.

Comment: Well, that does in turn make `Checkbox` depend on the imported `Dateselect` as well. [Avoid such circular references](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46593566/1048572)! Just import the `Button` module directly.

Comment: Yep @Bergi is right - just import `Checkbox` directly. Using the `index` pattern is great for defining internal APIs and maintaining strict module boundaries but you can't refer back to it from a component which it imports from. If you want to stick to the index pattern, break up the `Checkbox` file into a mini module `/components/CheckBox/Checkbox.js` and `/components/CheckBox/index.js` and import from that index file.

Comment: Thanks Bergi and @MarcDavies! I have one question though, as I’d like to keep the index pattern, why would moving Checkbox to a mini module like that fix the issue? I’m not really clear on why my DateSelect component works at all having those circular dependencies haha.

Comment: OK @YoTengoUnLCD I'll write it as an answer as it is difficult to format in this comment block.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you have a circular dependency on the export in `/components/index.js`.

When your build tool first builds your application, it does the following...

- starts at, say, `app.js`, which imports `DateSelect` from `components/index.js`
- goes to `components/index.js` which declares its export

  ```
  // SPOILER: This guy is your problem. We'll call him the douche.
  export {
    DateSelect,
    Button,
    Checkbox,
  };
  ```
- for the douche to be declared, it needs to import stuff from `components/DateSelect.js`, `components/Button.js` and `components/Checkbox.js`
- goes to these files and starts building what is in them
- as soon as it goes to build `DateSelect`, it is told to import `CheckBox` from `components/index.js`
- it already knows about the douche in `components/index.js`, so it goes looking for `CheckBox` on the douche (it 'circles' back to it), but `CheckBox` has not been declared in `components/CheckBox.js` yet, so it returns `undefined`

This is a matter of timing. `CheckBox` will be defined on the douche a few clicks after we try to import it, but that's a few clicks too late for your build.

You can show this by logging `CheckBox` immediately and a few milliseconds after the import statement...

```
// /components/DateSelect/DateSelect.js:

import { Checkbox } from '../';
console.log(CheckBox); // undefined
setTimeout(() => console.log(CheckBox), 4) // function CheckBox(_ref) { ...
```

So, when you try to declare `MyCustomCheckbox`, `CheckBox` is undefined.

By the time `DateSelect`'s render method has been called, `CheckBox` has been declared. This is, relatively, waaay later than the build process.

There is no 100% safe solution to this kind of problem as it depends on your application structure as a whole. It is usually best to avoid circling back to the same module

**Avoid the douche**

You can avoid circling back to the douche by importing directly from `components/CheckBox.js` or take the indexed module approach one level deeper and create a little CheckBox module...

```
/components
  /CheckBox
    CheckBox.js
    index.js
```

...then `import {CheckBox} from '/components/Checkbox'`

Comment: The douche is *not* an object. While it looks similar to an object literal, it just a declaration of the exported names. The only difference to your suggestion (`export {DateSelect} from './DateSelect';`) is that's it's equivalent to `export {default as DateSelect} from './DateSelect';`, not `export {DateSelect as DateSelect} from './DateSelect';`.

Comment: OK @Bergi so I misunderstood the nature of the douche under the hood. Will edit that out. But it is true that using the douche method creates an export entity which has a stable identity which the build tool circles back to. So - the approach of using individual export statements works. I'm also not sure why you criticise the named export method - it's clearly cleaner.

Comment: @Bergi Is it appropriate/helpful to downvote an answer which responds directly to the question and offers working solutions but which makes a small technical error? In any case - the implementation of module loading isn't exactly transparent so I don't think referring to exports as objects for this kind of explanation is too great a crime.

Comment: I'm not sure how far your misunderstanding goes, you get some things right and others (minor ones?) not, yet you arrive at a wrong solution. Thanks for fixing the term object, the next inaccuracy would be "*but `CheckBox` has not been declared yet*" - actually it has been declared (that's why it's found there), but it's not yet *initialised*. I've dowvoted mostly for the first "solution", which can't really work - it doesn't make a difference to change the re-export syntax. It still circles back to the `index.js` module, all you changed was default export vs named export.

Comment: @Bergi . 1. re instantiation vs declaration. I'm using 'declare' here to refer to the whole declaration -> instantiation -> assignment flow. Technically, `CheckBox` has been both declared and instantiated as undefined but not yet assigned. I think this level of detail is more distracting than helpful for this answer so I think using declare is appropriate. 2. Having done a bit more testing on my 'Kill the douche' solution, there's a bit of a gotcha in there. It does make a difference to change the re-export syntax. BUT what matters is the ordering of the re-export statements...

Comment: ...When I had it working, I happened to have the statements ordered in a way which meant that `CheckBox` was fully declared (declared + instantiated + assigned) in time. When you switch the order, this doesn't happen in time. In any case, it's not a stable solution so I'll edit out.

Comment: Yes, the ordering of the `import` (or `export from`) statements is the relevant one, as it determines in which order the cycle is resolved. It's a fine solution, but a fragile one. (Depending on the exact dependency graph, not necessarily less fragile than importing the module directly by avoiding the index)

Comment: Yes - but even if you order the `import` statements well, using a single export statement breaks it. In any case - importing direct from `CheckBox.js` (or another index file) is way safer.