# How does JavaScript's ES6 import work with circular dependencies?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

**test.html**

```
<script type="module" src="./B.js"></script>
```

**A.js**

```
import {bar} from './B.js';
import {test} from './B.js';

export function foo() {
    bar();
}

test();
console.log("IN A");
```

**B.js**

```
import {foo} from './A.js';

export function bar() {
    if (Math.random()) {
        foo();
    }
}

export function test() {
    console.log("test");
}

console.log("IN B");
```

The output is:

```
B.js:30 test
A.js:24 IN A
B.js:33 IN B
```

Why is "In B" the last line of code that gets executed? Also, if in test.html, `src="./A.js"`, "IN B" is the first line that gets executed.

Comment: How does that work with circular imports though?

Comment: You know what, I think this question may be more related.  This answer goes into a ton of detail about circular dependencies: [How to fix this ES6 module circular dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42704874/691711)

Comment: my circular import ended up with `Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type`