# how to use a class's method in another function outside the class?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I want to use the class `Coordinates`'s methods `compX` and `compY` outside the `class` and inside another function how can I do this I am getting the error `ReferenceError: xy is not defined`

I tried making the object inside the other function `drawGraph()` but it still gives an error.

```
<script>
var c =document.getElementById("myCanvas"); 
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
//function call
drawGraph(ctx,-10,10);
drawAxis(ctx,10);

function f(x){
        return x*x;
}

class Coordinates {
    Coordinates(){}
    compX(x){
        originX = myCanvas.width/2;
        mag = 20;
        return(originX + mag*x);
    }
    compY(y){
        originY = myCanvas.height/2;
        mag = 20;
        return(originY - mag*y);
    }
}

xy = new Coordinates();
function drawGraph(ctx, a, b){
//make lines that trace coordinates of the function in an interval
    var n = 50;
    var dx  = (b-a)/n;
    for(x=a; x<=b; x+=dx){
    var pointAx=x;
    var pointAy=f(x);
    var pointBx=x+dx;
    var pointBy=f(x+dx);
    console.log(`[${pointAx}, ${pointAy}],[${pointBx}, ${pointBy}]`)


    ctx.moveTo(xy.compX(pointAx), xy.compY(pointAy)); //this is where the error occurs
    ctx.lineTo(xy.compX(pointBx), xy.compY(pointBy));
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#0000ff"
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    } 
}

function drawAxis(ctx, axisLength){
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.moveTo(xy.compX(0), xy.compY(axisLength));
    ctx.lineTo(xy.compX(0), xy.compY(-axisLength));
    ctx.moveTo(xy.compX(axisLength), xy.compY(0));
    ctx.lineTo(xy.compX(-axisLength), xy.compY(0));
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
}

</script>
```

I am getting the error `ReferenceError: xy is not defined` 
I was expecting a graph to be plotted but nothing got displayed
please also tell how i can make the code better(neat)

Comment: `drawGraph` is called before `xy` is defined, but `drawGraph` uses `xy`.

Comment: Please use `var xy = new Coordinates();` instead of just `xy = ...`. Then in the class, use the `constructor` method, not the `Coordinates(){}`.

Comment: @SebastianSimon `xy` is defined just before drawGraph

Comment: @DragosStrugar I did that but it's still giving error `TypeError: xy is undefined` at the same line

Comment: @Manik `xy` is defined _after_ `drawGraph` is **called**.

Comment: @DragosStrugar This will just make `xy` undefined when `drawGraph` is called. The variable needs to be declared and defined _before_ `drawGraph` is called.

Comment: @SebastianSimon I got it thanks but it's still giving error `ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable originX`

Comment: @Manik This error is self-explanatory. Declare `originX`.

Comment: @SebastianSimon yes I know but overall not declaring variables in JS is bad practise and should be avoided. My answer encapsulates your notes, and I added several tips/things to avoid.

Comment: @DragosStrugar Yes, but just declaring isn’t enough. The declarations and calls needed to be moved as well.

Comment: @Manik `const`. If you can’t use `const`, `let`. If you [can’t use `let`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42704874/4642212), `var`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several things are wrong here, here is the better version of the code:

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

class Coordinates {
    compX(x) {
        var originX = myCanvas.width / 2;
        var mag = 20;
        return originX + mag * x;
    }
    compY(y) {
        var originY = myCanvas.height / 2;
        var mag = 20;
        return originY - mag * y;
    }
}

var xy = new Coordinates();

drawGraph(ctx, -10, 10);
drawAxis(ctx, 10);

function f(x) {
    return x * x;
}

function drawGraph(ctx, a, b) {
    //make lines that trace coordinates of the function in an interval
    var n = 50;
    var dx = (b - a) / n;
    for (x = a; x <= b; x += dx) {
        var pointAx = x;
        var pointAy = f(x);
        var pointBx = x + dx;
        var pointBy = f(x + dx);
        console.log(`[${pointAx}, ${pointAy}],[${pointBx}, ${pointBy}]`);

        ctx.moveTo(xy.compX(pointAx), xy.compY(pointAy)); //this is where the error occurs
        ctx.lineTo(xy.compX(pointBx), xy.compY(pointBy));
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#0000ff";
        ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    }
}

function drawAxis(ctx, axisLength) {
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.moveTo(xy.compX(0), xy.compY(axisLength));
    ctx.lineTo(xy.compX(0), xy.compY(-axisLength));
    ctx.moveTo(xy.compX(axisLength), xy.compY(0));
    ctx.lineTo(xy.compX(-axisLength), xy.compY(0));
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
}
```

First, get used to writing `var/let/const` before variable assignment. That was causing your some of the erros you've had. Second, as several people mentioned in the comments, you were getting the error because the function `drawGraph()` called `xy` before `xy` got assigned. Moving `xy` higher in the definition should solve your problem of `xy unassigned`.

Then, do not use empty constructor like you did. If you have something in the constructor, define it as `constructor()` and not `className()`.

Comment: can i somehow declare `originX` , `originY` and `mag` outside the function?

Comment: yes, add it to the global scope (before `class` declaration)