# imported variable is somehow being accessed before initialization

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

This is how my code looks

**index.html**:

```
<canvas></canvas>
```

**main.js**:

```
    import Class from "./module.js"
    export const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas") 
    const obj = new Class(args)
```

**module.js:**

```
import { canvas } from "./main.js"
const c = canvas.getContext("2d")

export default class Class{
// code
}
```

This is the error: Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'canvas' before initialization (in module.js)

What am I doing wrong?

tried with import function and some other stuff but that's not really efficient.

Comment: See [How to fix this ES6 module circular dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38841469/how-to-fix-this-es6-module-circular-dependency)

Comment: @Unmitigated that was too lengthy and i dont have the time (sorry) so i included the module in the head tag before the main one and it works. atleast for the canvas variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the canvas declaration to another file that the other two modules import.

canvas.js:

```
export const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas")
```

Then, main.js and module.js can import it like so:

```
import { canvas } from "./canvas.js"
```

Comment: That works but is it really the right approach? Thanks a lot though

Comment: @Fexxix It is a general method of fixing circular imports. There is nothing wrong with this approach.

Comment: alright, was worried there for a sec that i might be doing something unconventional. Again, thank u very much