# RequireJS - managing circular dependencies

Tags: javascript, requirejs

`ModuleA` requires `ModuleB`, which requires `ModuleC`, which requires `ModuleA`.

I'm dealing with this through the following (in `ModuleA`):

```
  define(["ModuleD"], function (moduleD) {
       var feedManager = {};
       require(["ModuleB"], function (moduleB) {
             feedManager.foo = moduleB.bar; // trivial example
       } 
       return feedManager;
  }
```

However occasionally, `feedManager.foo` is not available at the time of invocation.  I don't want to pepper my code with calls to "wait until this thing is available" - is there any way to force requireJS to handle this for me, or is there another pattern I should leverage?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RequireJS, Circular Dependencies and Exports "Magic" Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28193382/requirejs-circular-dependencies-and-exports-magic-method)

Comment: @QuentinRoy I don't feel that this addresses my question.

Comment: Right. I apologize this looks different indeed.

Comment: Are you already taking advantage of the [shim config](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim)?