# Instantiating objects with requireJS

Tags: requirejs

I have a model object defined like this

```
blog.js

define({title: '', url: '', summary: ''});
```

I'm using the `blog` model to hold data from a service and I need to populate an array of `blogs`. How do I instantiate a new `blog` within a loop in another module?

I've tried passing in `blog` as a require object, but it maintains it's reference inside the loop leaving an array of the same object over and over again.

```
othermodule.js

define(['blog'], function(blog) {
//... more code
  $.each(data, function(index, b) {
    var tmpBlog = blog;
    //...
    list.push(tmpBlog);
  });
});
```

I've also tried using `var blog = require('blog');` yielding the same result.

So how do I instantiate the blog object using requirejs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I figured it out. I defined the `blog` model incorrectly. I needed to return a `function blog(){...}` instead like so:

```
define(function() {
  return function blog() {
    var self = this;
    this.title = '';
    //...
  };
});
```

and the other module used it like this:

```
define(['models/blog'], function (model) {
  var tmpBlog = new model();
  tmpBlog.title = 'some title';
}
```

Comment: yes was just about to post that. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869530/requirejs-how-to-define-modules-that-contain-a-single-class) gives a lot more detail on the approach.