# RequireJS: How to define a constructor?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, constructor, requirejs

I want to create constructors according to the AMD specification. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869530/requirejs-how-to-define-modules-that-contain-a-single-class) and tried to follow it. Here's what I ended up with:

### main.js

```
requirejs.config({

    paths: {
        'jquery': 'vendor/jquery-1.9.1.min',
        'lodash': 'vendor/lodash-1.3.1.min',
        'knockout': 'vendor/knockout-2.2.1.min',
        'bootstrap': 'vendor/bootstrap-2.3.2.min'
    }
});

requirejs(
    ['jquery', 'lodash', 'knockout', 'controller/categories'], 
    function main($,_,ko, CategoriesCtrl) {

        var categories = new CategoriesCtrl();

    }
);
```

### controller/categories.js

```
define('categories', function() {

    return function CategoriesCtrl(layers) {

        var self = this;
        layers = layers || [];

        console.log(ko);

    };
});
```

The result I get is that CategoriesCtrl is undefined. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have created [a named AMD module](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#modulename) by making your first argument to `define` `'categories'`. It's best to avoid this where possible:

> You can explicitly name modules yourself, but it makes the modules
>   less portable -- if you move the file to another directory you will
>   need to change the name. It is normally best to avoid coding in a name
>   for the module and just let the optimization tool burn in the module
>   names.

Try adjusting `categories.js` to this:

```
define(function() {

    return function CategoriesCtrl(layers) {

        // etc

    };
});
```

Comment: I had a similar problem, but it turned out that I just forgot to put "return" ahead of the constructor.