# javascript typeerror it's not a constructor

Tags: javascript, jasmine

There is a javascript file with require js framework

```
init: function(){
    var self = this;
    self.commonSolutionManager = new solution.CommonSolutionManager();        
 },
```

I am creating jasmine test cases for testing the above code . I am creating an object for the above file with this constructor

```
function solution()
  {
    CommonSolutionManager =  function(){};
  }
```

but it's throwing error "TypeError: solution.CommonSolutionManager is not a constructor"

Comment: You're missing the "er" at the end of `CommonSolutionManag` in your upper section.

Comment: I edited it but @gpgekko reversed it

Comment: @abhishekvashistha Not on purpose, I added a tag. I guess our edits came in the same time or something. =S Sorry about that, edited it back in

Comment: No problem , I was just trying to say that it is not the main reason of error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This block of code places your constructor inside a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) which scopes the constructor to ONLY be accessible with in the closure.

```
function solution()
{
    CommonSolutionManager =  function(){};
}
```

This block of code tries to access the constructor as if it where a property of solution; but it's not, it's more like a private variable with in the solution function.

```
self.commonSolutionManager = new solution.CommonSolutionManag();
```

You probably wanted your constructor to be defined in the following way.

```
// create the solution object and store it in the global namespace
solution = window.solution || {}; 

// create the constructor
solution.CommonSolutionManag = function() {};

// now you can use the constructor
var csm = new solution.CommonSolutionManag();
```

NOTE: If you're using requireJS, then this probably isn't the approach you want to take. See [RequireJS: How to define a constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17368491/requirejs-how-to-define-a-constructor)

Comment: as the jasmine project is already setup and there is already globalsetup.js file which is already pushed in karma.config.js file . still getting the error . @Scott Boring

Comment: I don't see how globalsetup.js or karma.config.js comes into play. These don't change the scoping effect of a closure. You probably need to add more of your code to the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `solution` as an object but it's a function. Not clear on how it should work but the following should fix the problem:

```
var solution = new function()  {
    this.CommonSolutionManager =  function(){};
}
```

And you can then use `new solution.CommonSolutionManager()`