# RequireJS dependency is undefined if I name the module

Tags: requirejs, durandal

I'm using Durandal, and I'm trying to use this module as a dependency for another module:

```
define('Beer', function () {
    return function Beer (name, brewery) {
        this.name = name;
        this.brewery = brewery;
    };
});
```

In the other module, I do this:

```
define(['knockout', 'models/Beer'], function (ko, Beer) {
    return {
        displayName: 'Add',
        name: ko.observable(),
        brewery: ko.observable(),
        save: function () {
            var beer = new Beer(this.name(), this.brewery());
            console.log(beer);
        }
    }
});
```

My javascript is loaded, because I define it in my paths (and I checked in Firebug). But the `Beer` argument in my second module is undefined. I don't know why, as my Beer module does return something (it returns the function). What else can I look at? Most solutions I find are that the (first) module isn't returning anything, but mine clearly is.

**UPDATE**
Apparently, when I remove the name of my Beer module, it works:

```
define(function() {
    return function Beer (name, brewery) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

Even though [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869530/requirejs-how-to-define-modules-that-contain-a-single-class) would seem to work, it doesn't for me. Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing named modules with anonymous modules in your approach.

If you name the module 'Beer',  you require it using the name, not the path:

```
require(['Beer'], function (Beer) {
    var a = new Beer();
});
```

If you remove the name from the Beer module, you have an anonymous module which you can load by path:

```
require(['path/to/Beer'], function (Beer) {
    var a = new Beer();
}
```

Edit: the topic you linked to does not use RequireJS, even though it looks similar.