# Call constructor/function by name, within requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have code like this

```
var e = new window[className](...);
```

where

```
className
```

is a name of some "class" I've created and is specified in an attribute in my html.
All I had to do was make sure I had loaded a constructor/function of the name in className and it worked.

I've started getting all my stuff into *require* and this has unsurprisingly stopped working. 
I have a file Eric.js which I have required, and contains

```
define('Eric',function(){
var Eric = function (ED) {
...
};
// etc

return Eric;
});
```

but

```
require(['wtt/Eric']);
className='Eric';
var e = new window[className](...);
```

produces

```
TypeError: window[className] is not a constructor
```

Comment: You should post more of your code, any error messages you get and things you have tried to do in order to resolve this.

Comment: I've included a sketch f what I am requiring. Hope that makes my problem clearer.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you will find answer [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869530/requirejs-how-to-define-modules-that-contain-a-single-class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be unaware that RequireJS operates *asynchronously*. Let's look at your code:

```
require(['wtt/Eric']);
className='Eric';
var e = new window[className](...);
```

The first line (`require...`) will cause RequireJS to *initiate* loading your module. You do not actually know *when* the module will be loaded. In fact, given the way JavaScript works, you are guaranteed that by the time `var e = new window[className](...);` executes, your module will *not* be loaded and this line will fail. So you have to structure you code so that the line which fails is guaranteed to run *after* the module is loaded. You do this by passing a callback to `require`:

```
require(['wtt/Eric'], function () {
    var e = new window['Eric'](...);
    ...
});
```

Or even better, don't leak anything in the global space and do:

```
require(['wtt/Eric'], function (Eric) {
    var e = new Eric();
    ...
});
```

Regarding the comment you left on the other answer, note that it is possible to compute what module to load at run time:

```
var mod = document.getElementById("myid").attributes.foo.value;
require(['wtt/' + mod], function (Constructor) {
    var e = new Constructor();
});
```

If you ever use `r.js` to combine your modules, you'll have to *explicitly* list the modules you load in the manner I've just shown above because `r.js` is not able to follow computed dependencies.

Comment: Yes, I just twigged the asynchronous issue. Moreover, I have also now come into contact with backbone and underscore. So what was a few days packaging has turned into a major overhaul. We arent getting any nearer to how I might go var thing= new window[$name]();

Comment: You've answered the question. But you've told me off for polluting the global namespace. But I still want the constructor name to be a variable, it's read from the document. I guess I can go  lookup['Eric']=Eric; new lookup[className]()

Answer (score 1):

Typical usage of `requirejs` is:

```
require(['wtt/Eric'], function(Eric) {
    var e = new Eric(...);
});
```

Is it possible for you to use `require` in that way?

P.S. By the way, you should avoid usage of global vars in your code and add small fix to `Eric` module definition:

```
define('Eric', function() {
    var Eric = function (ED) { // <- here comes the "var" keyword
        // ...
    };
    // etc

    return Eric;
});
```

You can read more let's say here: http://www.w3.org/wiki/JavaScript_best_practices#Avoid_globals

Comment: thanks. I'll fix my globals. my problem is I dont know what 'Eric' is going to be, it might be MapEric or some other sub class I have cooked up.  I will read this name in from the HTML, i.e. it's an attribute value in a div tag. I can just build a switch table, but I like being able to go "run the function of this name". I've looked at window[] and it doesnt seem to have my "required" stuff.